# Does every plane curve contain a rational point?

Tags: irrational-numbers, plane-curves

Does every plane curve contain a rational point?

I think the answer is yes, but I can not prove this. Please help.

However, if it is possible to build a pathological curve - without rational points, then even more interesting question arises - which properties of a curve will imply existence of a rational point?

Comment: The answer is NO. e.g. $y = x + \pi$ doesn't contain any rational points.

Comment: @achillehui if we take $x = -\pi$ then this curve contains $0$ which is pretty rational.

Comment: Not necessarily because $x=\pi $ is a curve which does not contain a rational point.

Comment: How about $(x-\pi)^2+(y-\pi)^2=0$?

Comment: @Jihad A [rational point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_point) in a plane means a point whose $x$ and $y$ coordinates are both rational.

Comment: @JohnBentin probably you want to say $x^2+y^2 = \pi^2$. This curve is pretty interesting but doesn't contain any point that have 2 rational coordinates. It's true.

Comment: @achille hui thanks, indeed it is simple, evident and beautiful counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is NO. We can show more by only considering straight lines and the fact that rational points are countable.
Choose an arbitrary point $A$ in ${{\mathbb{R}}^{2}}$ whose coordinates are both irrational. The set $L = \left\{ l:A\in l \right\}$ is uncountable, and thus there is no one-to-one mapping from $L$ to ${{\mathbb{Q}}^{2}}$. Hence, there are uncountably many lines going through $A$ which contains no rational points.
If we go further, we can show that ${{\mathbb{R}}^{2}} - {{\mathbb{Q}}^{2}}$ is path-connected.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and for "If we go further", part.